# Assign a value derrived from a cmd command to a bat variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm new to batch scripting and have encountered an issue.
I am running a command to get the GPU utilization, and I want to substring it
so that I can use the utilization as a integer.

Running `nvidia-smi -q -d UTILIZATION` 
gives me this output:

```
GPU 00000000:01:00.0
    Utilization
        Gpu                         : 100 %
        Memory                      : 0 %
        Encoder                     : 0 %
        Decoder                     : 0 %
```

Here is the relevant bat part:

```
:checkGPUUtil
cd nvsmiPath
goto :loop
timeout 1
goto :start

:loop

if %tries% leq 3 (
    set /a tries +=1
    sleep 10
    goto :loop
)
```

So what I am looking for is to copy the value shown in the GPU column, which is currently 100 and assign it to an integer.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: There is nothing whatsoever in the code snippet you have provided which shares any relevance to the question you have posed, nor the output you show as having received. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47871524/edit) your question appropriately.

Comment: Did you consider perhaps trying `nvidia-smi --query-gpu=utilization.gpu` or `nvidia-smi --query-gpu=utilization.gpu --format=csv`

Comment: …and if you wanted a continuous loop every 10 seconds, you may find that appending `-l 10` or `--loop=10` would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for %%a in (gpu1 gpu2) do set "%%a="
for /f "tokens=1,2delims=: " %%a in ('nvidia-smi -q -d UTILIZATION'
 ) do if "%%a"=="Gpu" if defined gpu1 (set /a gpu2=%%b) else (set /a gpu1=%%b)

echo GPU : %gpu1% and %gpu2%
set gpu
```

Execute the command (in single quotes) tokenising on <kbd>:</kbd> and <kbd>Space</kbd>, selecing the first and second tokens. If the first token exactly matches `Gpu` then assign the second token to the variable.

See `for /f` from the prompt (or examples here on SO) for documentation.

[modified for 2 gpus - mentioning this info in the original question would have made the task easier.]

Comment: This *almost* works. Since I am running two GPU's, it takes the second GPU's values. How can I make it break on the first match?

Comment: Thanks, your updated version works.
I will read on how for /f works.
Sorry for not mentioning that ive got two gpu's, didnt even think about it, I thought it was going to match the first and then quit